# 3 layers of embedded quotes, JS function not registering variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The code looks something like this:

```
<?php
 $page->startscript();
  echo "
    function f1(id){
        $('#def').html('<button class=\'btn btn-danger\' onclick=\'f2(id);\'>act</button>');
    }
    function f2(id){
        alert(id);
    }
  ";
 $page->endscript();
?>
```

The `startscript()`, `endscript()` thing works fine, it just allows me to add JS to the page.  What doesn't work is id isn't carried over from f1 to f2, its just returning blank.  I think it has something to do with the quotes and not being treated as a variable. If I pass an int as the parameter for the onclick attribute it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables aren't expanded inside strings in Javascript (ES6 adds "template strings", which support this), you need to use concatenation. And assuming `id` is a string, you need to put quotes around it in the function call.

```
   echo"
      function f1(id){
          $('#def').html('<button class=\'btn btn-danger\' onclick=\'f2(\"' + id + '\");\'>act</button>');
      }
      function f2(id){
          alert(id);
      }
      ";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's got to do with the context of your f2 function.

Since the function isn't present on the page, the scope in which the rendered JS is looking can't really find the function you've declared.

I've created a basic fiddle that shows you how you can achieve what you're looking to do here. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pw9somoa/)

Basically, your js will call the f1 function like so:

```
function f1(id) {
  $('#def').append('<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="f2(' + id + ');">act</button>');
}

f1("10");
```

your HTML will need to look something like this:

```
<div id="def">
</div>
<script>
  function f2(id){
    alert(id);
  }
</script>
```

Also, the JS that you're rendering is literally passing in the id to f2 as a string and not the value.

Hopefully you can see what you need to do.